# 'out' issue in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, reference, compiler-warnings

When in C# we have the `out` and `ref` parameter options, in VB there is a only one: **`ByRef`**.

Now, little 'problem' when trying to 'eliminate' the compiler warning saying that test was not initialized before passing as argument:

```
Dim test As MyParsableClass ' = Nothing  need imperatively?? '
' some code ... '
MyParsableClass.TryParse("value", test) ' warning on "test" here
```

the class brief declaration:

```
Class MyParsableClass

  Public Shared Function TryParse(ByVal value As String, _
    ByRef myParsableClass As MyParsableClass) As Boolean
    myParsableClass = Nothing
    If True Then
      ' parse code OK'
      myParsableClass = New MyParsableClass()
      Return True
    Else
      ' parse code NOK '
      ' myParsableClass remains Nothing '
      Return False
    End If

  End Function

End Class
```

maybe a solution was to declare

```
...Optional ByRef myParsableClass As MyParsableClass = Nothing)
```

but I can't set this parameter as optional one. What will happen if I'll miss it?

**PS.** (edit)

In the real project, my "parsable" class is `MyHour` with `Hour` and `Minute` properties. I wrote already the `Parse(value as String)` with a FormatException, but I think the code could be more clear, compact and quick when I will not use try catch blocks...

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: @divo: How to eliminate the warning (without `#pragma` or other similar tricks)?

Comment: So is there a problem when you initialize the local variable with `Nothing`?

Comment: no, but VB.NET looks like limited from this POV

Comment: Then you might find these comments interesting: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=90489 and http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=90678. Adding `= Nothing` to the variable declaration seems not too much work as compared to an overly complicated static analyzer in the compiler (that might increase compilation time for each build process). After all, this is a warning and not a compiler error.

Comment: @divo: Yes, but when I worked in C# projects I always tried to code with 0 warnings and 0 errors.

Comment: @serhio - as you and divo have both aluded, there is a way to code here with 0 warnings and 0 errors - perform the "Nothing" assignment. Different languages have different voodoo incantations to appease the compilers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not believe it's possible to prevent this warning, without an explicit assignment.

Different languages have different features/facilities - if they didn't, there'd only be one programming language :-) In this case, yes, VB doesn't pretend that there are two types of ref parameters, as C# does - so far as the CLR is concerned, "out" doesn't exist.

And I'm not sure what peSHIr is talking about - TryParse was *added* to later releases of the BCL for precisely the situation where a parse is as likely to fail as to succeed - so you can take a faulting path without requiring an exception to be thrown.

*Edit*

To add - the reason you don't get a warning for many of the built in types for which a TryParse exists (e.g. Int32) is because they're Structs/Value types, and hence always have a value. If your class is simple enough, would it be logical for it to be a Structure instead?

Comment: as I mentioned, the (real) MyHour class could be really a structure... this is an interesting idea.

Comment: I can't declare MyHour as structure... there are used as optional parameters. Optional parameters can't be structures.

Comment: Also structures can't have parameter-less constructors nor protected members, their members can't be initialized when declaring, I can't implement IComparable with Equals(object) etc etc..

Comment: Ah, this is why I asked whether it would be logical - obviously, I didn't know which additional constraints you had on your implementation - although (in the specific instance of) Optional parameters may be better dealt with as NUllable<T> or overloads - it's friendlier to non-VB languages.

Comment: It was not a bad idea that something like `TryParse` was added (as an option to just always getting an `Exception` on `Parse`), but the way it was implemented (=using an `out` parameter) that many people think was a bad call. Microsoft is in this camp, which is why you get the warning serhio was asking about.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly an answer to your question, but [out and ref/ByRef are bad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413218/best-practice-of-using-the-out-keyword-in-c/413236#413236), so why use them in the first place? Many developers think that the `TryParse` paradigm in the .NET Framework 1.0 was a bad way to go.

Why not go for a `MyParsableClass` that has a `Public Shared Function Parse(ByVal value As String) As MyParsableClass` method that raises an appropriate exception when needed?

Or even a `Public Shared Function Parse(ByVal value As String) As MyParsableClassParsed` where, `MyParsableClassParsed` is a helper inner class that contains two readonly properties: `Success As Boolean` and `Result As MyParsableClass`? You could then always get a result from calling `Parse`, but you'd get `Success==True` and `Result==[whatever]`, or simply `Success==False` and `Result==Nothing`.

Also, your `MyParsableClassParsed` helper class could also use an enumerator instead of a boolean and/or a list of error messages to tell the caller how/why the parse operation failed. Or the throw exception might have such an enumerated value and/or error message(s).

Much easier to use and more flexible. And all without `ByRef` to give you headaches/warnings.

Comment: in reality, my parsable class is `MyHour` with `Hour` and `Minute` properties. This will not be very clear if I'll add also `Success` and `Result` properties... I wrote already the `Parse(value as String)` with a FormatException, but the code is more clear, compact and quick when I don't use try catch blocks...

Comment: Just pointing that all objects not derived from System.ValueType are handled ByRef implicitly, ie your class is ByRef whether you specify it in the method parameter list, or not.

Comment: @Monkey: you are wrong. ByRef can set the external reference to nothing inside the calling method, ByVal can't.

Comment: @Monkey:  All parameters are passed ByVal by default, even reference types.  The only time parameters are passed by reference is when the ByRef keyword is used.

Comment: @serhio: Ah, for such a "simple" case (I assumed more complex parsing), you probably have `MyHour` defined as a `Struct` (not a `Class` and you could define a TypeConverter for it. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1866552/1866620#1866620

Comment: @peSHIr: already discussed. See the Damien_The_Unbeliever comments.